# Cucumber unable to locate element - first scenario passes and subsequent ones fail

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

[image]
I am running cucumber tests with selenium/TestNG and reporting via html. The first scenario passes fine but subsequent ones fail when they should be passing, due to being unable to locate an element. The second scenario (the one failing) is almost identical to the first, it is just checking whether a different element on the page is displayed - which it definitely is. This is what my feature file looks like:

```
Feature: LoginFeature
  This deals with logging in

  Scenario: Log in with correct username

    Given I navigate to the login page
    And I enter the following login details:
      | username | password |
      | cukey    | passwoid |
    And I click the login button
    Then I should land on the newest page

  Scenario: Log in with correct username part 2

    Given I navigate to the login page
    And I enter the following login details:
      | username | password |
      | cukey    | passwoid |
    And I click the login button
    Then I should land on the newest page by other measure

  Scenario: Log in with correct username to fail

    Given I navigate to the login page
    And I enter the following login details:
      | username | password |
      | cukey    | passwoid |
    And I click the login button
    Then I should land on the newest page wrongly
```

Here are my step definitions/implementations (the @then with "middle name" is the one that should be passing):

```
package Steps;

import Base.BaseUtil;
import Pages.LoginPageObjeks;
//import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MaStepdefs extends BaseUtil {
    private BaseUtil base;

    public MaStepdefs(BaseUtil base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @And("^I click the login button$")
    public void iClickTheLoginButton() throws Throwable {
        LoginPageObjeks page = new LoginPageObjeks(base.Driver);
        page.ClickLogin();

    }

    @Given("^I navigate to the login page$")
    public void iNavigateToTheLoginPage() throws Throwable {

        base.Driver.navigate().to("http://www.executeautomation.com/demosite/Login.html");

    }

    @And("^I enter the following login details:$")
    public void iEnterTheFollowingLoginDetails(DataTable table) throws Throwable {

        List<List<String>> data = table.asLists(String.class);
        String userName = data.get(1).get(1);
        String passWord = data.get(1).get(0);

        List<User> users = new ArrayList();
        users.add(new User(userName, passWord));

        LoginPageObjeks page = new LoginPageObjeks(base.Driver);

        for (User user : users)
            page.Login(user.username, user.password);


        //List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        //users = table.asList(User.class);




            Thread.sleep(2000);


        }

        @Then("^I should land on the newest page$")
        public void iShouldLandOnTheNewestPage () throws Throwable {
            Assert.assertEquals("It's not displayed", base.Driver.findElement(By.id("Initial")).isDisplayed(), true);
        }


    @Then("^I should land on the newest page wrongly$")
    public void iShouldLandOnTheNewestPageWrongly() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertEquals("It's not displayed", base.Driver.findElement(By.id("fish")).isDisplayed(), true);
    }

    @Then("^I should land on the newest page by other measure$")
    public void iShouldLandOnTheNewestPageByOtherMeasure() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertEquals("It's not displayed", base.Driver.findElement(By.id("Middle Name")).isDisplayed(), true);
    }

}

    class User {
        public String username;
        public String password;

        public User(String userName, String passWord) {
            username = userName;
            password = passWord;
        }
    }
```

And here is my test runner:

```
package Runner;


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/features"}, plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty"}, glue = "Steps")

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Is there something I need to add for TestNG to run multiple scenarios? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: The first three steps for all scenarios are identical, but they have different expected outcomes?  Since you logged in the same way all three times, I'm confused why the test would expect a different landing page.

Comment: If you are reusing same first steps of all scenarios in single feature file, consider using background (google it, it is well documented, 'Cucumber - background') another thing is, keep your test scenarios to the point, your scenarios should in perfect world test SINGLE functionality, instead it would be better to create one scenario that is testing login process, one scenario that test that you will be unable to login with incorrect details etc.

Comment: They aren't identical. The second one is checking a different element is displayed on the page (which is there and should pass) and the third one is the same but is checking for an element that isn't there - it is intended to fail. I will try using Background but I still can't see why it wouldn't work this way

Comment: my apologies, I was being an idiot an using the wrong element selector. Thanks for the help though